# Easy way to export javadocs

Tags: java, html, javadoc

How would I export all my javadoc comments into a HTML pages similar to:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html

or

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: A JDK includes a command called *javadoc*. Just google for the usage of this command.

Answer (score 1):

easy way... I would go with maven javadoc plugin.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/

Comment: Is the OP using maven?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do so with NetBeans. Right click on your project in the **projects panel**, click on **Generate JavaDoc**. If there's no error in your code, it will generate an HTML documentation automatically for your project and you're gonna find it, usually, in the **dist** folder of your project. I didn't check for Eclipse, but it must be a similar process in Eclipse, with one or clicks you generate your javadoc. 
Update: Eclipse method: Select **Project** –> **Generate JavaDoc**